# Cloning Git-Hub repository from docker Jenkins instance

Tags: git, docker, jenkins

When I try to do the following inside the docker container:

```
git clone <GIT_REPO>
```

I get this error:

```
fatal: unable to access <GIT_REPO>: gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
```

In order to fix this I tried adding my git-hub username/password to Jenkins "credentials" and it doesn't work.

**(P.S. Git-hub repo is on the enterprise github and I'm connected to enterprise network)**

Can you please guide me on how to fix this?

Comment: Try to add those envvars to display more debug output: `export GIT_TRACE=true; export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=true`

Comment: You may also try to find some information in the logs of your github enterprise.